# Error while trying to import a jdl file to a jhipster project using mongodb

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to import a jdl file, but I get the Error: Enumeration values must be passed to get the formatted values.

Any insight?

```
entity Post {
    name String,
    details String,
    image BLOB,
    video BLOB,
    document BLOB,
    user String
}

entity Reviews {
    content Integer,
    user String,
    message String,
    date LocalDate
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Post{winner(nickname)} to Reviews,
    Post{loser(nickname)} to Reviews
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BLOB` is not a valid [JDL](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/intro) field type, try `Blob` instead (capitalization is important).

For more information you can check [Field types and validations](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields#field-types-and-validations).